# Html 5 Input accept Video Capture or Video Upload

Tags: html, video, mobile, upload

Using HTML 5 it is now possible to use video capture on an input like so:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camcorder"/>
```

The OS of the mobile device drops into the recorder immediately and allows video capture.

The problem is, on most mobile devices it doesn't give you an option to use an existing video file.

However, I'm looking for a way to give the user a choice: **Either Capture New Video or Upload an Existing Video**.

I believe one solution would be to make 2 inputs (one for live capture and the other for a file upload) and then prompt the user for which one they desire.

My question is:

**Is there additional information I can put on a SINGLE input that will allow the user (or tell the OS device) to allow capture or allow upload?**

Something that might look like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camcorder;fileupload"/>
```

The above code is not functional just what I might believe to be a future solution.

It seems silly that most mobile OS's don't allow the user to select an existing file, since the end result is generally the same: The user is selecting a file on the system to upload.

Comment: For mobile, remove the `capture` part. Simply `<input type="file" accept="video/*" />` does exactly what you wanted: "Phone will show options including `recording now` and `select an existing one`"

Answer (score 0):

they need to improve INPUT  with better attributes....
if your on https you can do it in code....
You gain access to camera with the users permission....
Yet its open to anything.<--wrong way
The best way is by Input with good attributes no permission needed with code.
The Input provides the way to grant or not grant by the action at hand by the user...
Access to mic feed input... a bowser dialog
Camera take picture input jpg with size and quality...
Its the user doing it not your code.....